# How to transform this object using Object.keys and filtering

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like:

```
const arr = {
[1]: [{id: 1, category: 1}, {id: 2, category: 2}], 
[2]: [{id: 3, category: 2}, {id: 4, category: 2}], 
[3]: [{id: 5, category: 3}, {id: 6, category: 3}]
}
```

Is it possible to move for example {id: 2, category: 2} to another place to have:

```
const arr = {
[1]: [{id: 1, category: 1}], 
[2]: [{id: 2, category: 2}, {id: 3, category: 2}, {id: 4, category: 2}], 
[3]: [{id: 5, category: 3}, {id: 6, category: 3}]
}
```

items with category = 2 should be in the array[2], 3 in 3 etc. It's possible to do that with Object.keys and filtering somehow? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: yes it is possible with `Object.keys` and `filtering` - a coding "style" tip ... you have `const arr = { ... }` - I would never call a variable containing an object (even if it does have numeric keys) `arr`

Comment: I really would expect a variable named `arr` to hold an array. Not a length-less object with integer-indexed one-based properties.

Comment: How was this object constructed in the first place?

Comment: Although probably not the OP's intent, `[1]: ` is actually valid syntax in ES6.

Comment: ... and does mean what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through `arr`, then using `array#reduce` you can group your array on the `category` value.

```js
const arr = {[1]: [{id: 1, category: 1}, {id: 2, category: 2}], [2]: [{id: 3, category: 2}, {id: 4, category: 2}], [3]: [{id: 5, category: 3}, {id: 6, category: 3}]},
    result = Object.keys(arr).reduce((r,k) => {
      arr[k].forEach(({id, category}) => {
        r[category] = r[category] || [];
        r[category].push({id, category});
      })
      return r;
    },{});

console.log(result);
```

You can use `array#concat` all the values of your object, then using `array#reduce` group object based on `category`.

```js
const arr = {[1]: [{id: 1, category: 1}, {id: 2, category: 2}], [2]: [{id: 3, category: 2}, {id: 4, category: 2}], [3]: [{id: 5, category: 3}, {id: 6, category: 3}]},
    result = [].concat(...Object.values(arr)).reduce((r,{id, category}) => {
      r[category] = r[category] || [];
      r[category].push({id, category});
      return r;
    },{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Object.keys can be used to traverse the array. Then, using Array.splice and Array.push, you can remove item and push it to proper place. Please check the following code:

```js
const arr = { 
              [1]: [{id: 1, category: 1}, {id: 2, category: 2}, {id: 7, category: 3}], 
              [2]: [{id: 3, category: 2}, {id: 4, category: 2}], 
              [3]: [{id: 5, category: 3}, {id: 6, category: 3}] 
            }; 
            
     Object.keys(arr).forEach(function(k){
     
        for(var j = 0; j < arr[k].length;j++) {
            if(arr[k][j].category!=k) {
              var removedItem = arr[k].splice(arr[k].indexOf(j), 1);
              var pushedArr = arr[removedItem[0].category];
 
              if(pushedArr) {
                pushedArr.push(removedItem[0]);
                
                j--;
              }
            }
        }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thanks, but not exactly, because if you have:

const arr = {
[1]: [{id: 1, category: 1}, {id: 2, category: 2}, {id: 7, category: 3}], 
[2]: [{id: 3, category: 2}, {id: 4, category: 2}], 
[3]: [{id: 5, category: 3}, {id: 6, category: 3}]
};

and you want to move id=2 to [2], and need to move id=7 to [3] (because id=7 has wrong category Id) this is not working properly.

Comment: I am updating the answer.